# NSMutableDictionary as datasource: can´t remove cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I use a NSMutableDictionary to populate my UITableView, which works just fine. However, I want to delete rows and then I have to remove the target cell from the Dictionary before I call the -reloadData method.

I´m having a hard time getting to the right object in the NSMutableDictionary and delete it. I´ll post the structure below.

```
country = [
{
    citys = [
        {
            id = 4;
            cityName = New York;
        },
        {
            id = 5;
            cityName = LA;
        }
    ];

    id = 2;
    countryName = US;
},
{
    citys = [
        {
            id = 21;
            cityName = Oslo;
        }
    ];

    id = 31;
    countryName = Norway;
}
```

];

I use the "countryName" values as header sections name. So, I know the cell that has been tapped, how I can find that object in the array and remove it.

Comment: [dict removeObjectForKey:[dict allKeysForObject:@"Oslo"][0]]

Comment: The proper data structure for a sectioned table view is an array of arrays. Anything else makes this much more difficult. The outer array represents the sections and each inner array represents the rows for the section. This makes it simple to get the proper data using the indexPath section and row values as indexes into the arrays. Actually you want an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains two keys - one for the title and the other for the inner array.

Comment: @rmaddy: i passed first object `[0]`, just thnkin only one city exists in list ;p. And i know this is not the best of answers

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sorry - I overlooked the array access. Never mind :)

Comment: @rmaddy: Nothing to mind... friend, As i always say "i am here to learn".

Comment: @rmaddy I´m having a lot of troubles implementing that, but I guess I´ll get back to it then. But your suggestion is an array of nsdictionaries. Because of the sections titles? Thank you both.

Comment: How do you "index" the dictionary in the first place, in order to extract the data you need in cellForRowAtIndexPath??

Comment: @HotLicks I just read it from a stored plist.

Comment: You say you use an NSMutableDictionary to populate your table.  How do you associate a row number with a dictionary value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope you won't mind, If I write some code for you. Don't just copy and paste it. Try to understand the way it is. So that you can tackle this kind of requirement in the future.**

I had your data in the `plist` and extracted it to the `NSMutableDictionary` and then `NSMutableArray` like this.

```
// In the viewDidLoad: method
NSMutableDictionary *plistData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Countries" ofType:@"plist"]];
sectionedArray = [plistData objectForKey:@"Country"];
```

then the following `tableView` methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [sectionedArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSMutableArray *array = [[sectionedArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"citys"];
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];;
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    NSMutableArray *array = [[sectionedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"citys"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"cityName"];
    return cell;
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSMutableArray *array = [[sectionedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"citys"];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSLog(@"Sectioned array %@", sectionedArray);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) syntax:

```
// NSInteger section, row;
NSDictionary *countryData = country[section];
NSMutableArray *cityData = countryData[@"citys"];
[cityData removeObjectAtIndex:row];
```

(note, for what it's worth: the English plural of *city* is *cities*.)